# zerorpc in multithreaded environment?

Tags: django, multithreading, zeromq, zerorpc

I'd like to use zerorpc as a internal service communication tool.

It seems zeromq can be perfectly used in multithread environments.
http://augustl.com/blog/2013/zeromq_instead_of_http/

However zerorpc documentation or tutorial is really sparse.

I'm trying to use zerorpc in a multithreaded environment (Django) and am stuck on to figure out how to reuse already connected socket (or pool of sockets) with zerorpc.

Is there an obvious solution?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a communication breakdown here.  ZeroMQ is great for multi-threaded environments, *provided you follow the rules*.

Rule # 1: ZMQ sockets are not thread-safe, you can't share them between threads.

That's the only rule.  The usefulness of ZMQ in a multi-threaded environment is to have each thread spin up its own sockets which can connect to sockets in other threads and thus allow a more streamlined communication between threads.

So, you don't want to reuse already connected sockets.  You want to create new sockets owned by your new threads.